# Rails 6 form authenticity_token not matching session[:_csrf_token]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, csrf-token

After upgrading our application to Rails 6 and using all of the default configuration settings (which include per-form CSRF tokens), I'm seeing that sometimes users receive `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`, however the form has the `authenticity_token` in its params when looking at the stack trace, it's just different than the session's `_csrf_token` attribute at the time. I can't reproduce it myself, but it's happening enough in our error monitoring tool that I'd like to correct it.

We aren't doing anything custom with the session configuration (as a matter of fact, we aren't doing any initializer for sessions at all), so I'm curious what would cause the session's token to not match the form's?

Comment: Is your session sticking properly? It's possible that it's being recreated each time. Check by looking at `session.id`.

Comment: Caching is one really common cause. If you have a reverse proxy in front of your server it will serve the same form (and thus the same CSRF token) to all the incoming requests.

Comment: @max is that possible if I can't reproduce it? Would it be the reverse proxy's fault (in our case, load balancer--HAProxy) if it's not happening to everyone?

Comment: @tadman same as above -- is it possible that's the case if it's not reproducible?

Comment: Try eliminating variables to see what happens. Go direct bypassing the proxy, etc.

Comment: @trevorhinesley I actually don't know, its not really my area expertise. Its is something that has burned me in the past though.

Comment: @tadman confirmed that our proxy has the appropriate X-Forwarded-* headers, so it must be something unrelated...

Comment: That's unrelated. You should be paying attention to `session.id` and in particular if the cookie is being accepted. A mismatched domain will cause cookie rejection and the session won't stick, so you'll get a new one on each request.

Comment: @tadman got it. But how would I go about checking if the cookie is being “accepted”?